# Is Rotter's Interpersonal Trust Scale fixed?

Tags: measurement

I am new to psychology and recently have been looking for a metric of trust. I found that Rotter's Interpersonal Trust Scale (IST) is widely used, so I checked the [original paper](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1968-18105-001) published by Rotter in 1967. But I didn't found the scale per se, and instead, I only found the constituents of the scale, which is 25 items plus 15 filler items.

Is the complete version published later in Rotter's other papers? Or the scale itself is intentionally left semi-designed and should be finalized on use?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Chun K-T, Campbell JB. Dimensionality of the Rotter Interpersonal Trust Scale. Psychol Rep. 1974;35: 1059–1070. doi:10.2466/pr0.1974.35.3.1059